# discordjs If attachment is not in the list, remove the attachment

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am developing a plugin and this is where I'm stuck. If one of the attachments uploaded more than once is not an image or a video, I try to remove the ones that are not, but I could not find any way to remove the faulty one.

```js
/* @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
  *  |  [ Image / Link Checker ]  |
  *  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ */
  // Allowed domains
  let allowedDomains = [];
  await db.query('SELECT imageChannel, linkChannel, warnChannel, allowedLinks FROM config WHERE server = ?', message.guild.id, async function(err, res, fields){
    if (err) throw err;
    // Validation
    const warnChannel = await res[0]['warnChannel'];
    let validAttachment = false;
    let validLink = false;
    let validContent = "";
    let imageChannel = [];
    imageChannel.push(res[0]['imageChannel']);
    let linkChannel = [];
    linkChannel.push(res[0]['linkChannel']);
    let allowedLinks = [];
    allowedLinks.push(res[0]['allowedLinks']);
    let disallowedLinks = [];
    disallowedLinks.push(res[0]['disallowedLinks']);
    // Allowed file extensions
    const allowedExtensions = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'mp4'];

    if (imageChannel.includes(message.channel.id)) {
      const attachments = message.attachments;
      
      if (attachments.size > 0) {
        let attachmentsList = [];
        
        attachments.forEach(async (attachment) => {
          fileExtension = attachment.name.toLowerCase().slice((attachment.name.lastIndexOf(".") - 1 >>> 0) + 2);
          
          if (!allowedExtensions.includes(fileExtension)) {
            attachmentsList.push(attachment);
            console.log(attachment.id);
            // Delete the message containing the attachment
            await message.attachments.delete(attachment.id);
            // Optionally, you can send a warning message to the user
            message.guild.channels.cache.get(warnChannel).send(`${message.author}, why are you sharing unauthorized content?`);
          }
        });
        attachmentsList.forEach(async (attachmentData) => {
          const attachmentsToDelete = message.attachments.filter((attachment) => attachment.id == attachmentData);

          if (attachmentsToDelete.size > 0) {
            try {
              // Delete the message containing the attachment
              await message.delete();
              console.log(`Deleted message with attachment ID: ${attachmentData}`);
            } catch (error) {
              console.error(`Error deleting message: ${error}`);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

If one of the attachments uploaded more than once is not an image or a video, I try to remove the ones that are not, but I could not find any way to remove the faulty one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than deleting, considering **editing** the message with the filtered Attachments.

```js
attachmentsList.forEach(async (attachmentData) => {
    const files = message.attachments.filter((attachment) => attachment.id !== attachmentData); // 1
    
    if (files.size !== message.attachments.size) { // 2
        try {
            await message.edit({ files }); // 3
            console.log(`Deleted message with attachment ID: ${attachmentData}`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error deleting message: ${error}`);
        }
    }
});
```

#### Changes:

1. Filter the attachments that you want to keep.
2. Checking if the number of attachments required are the same as the original message, better than the previous "to delete" check.
3. Edit the message with the new filtered attachments.

Comment: how to fix? ```
(node:16008) ExperimentalWarning: buffer.Blob is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Error deleting message: DiscordAPIError[50005]: Cannot edit a message authored by another user
```

Comment: are you trying to edit a message that was not sent by your bot? if you're initial goal was to delete a specific attachment from a single message, then its not possible. The user who sent it has to delete it themselves. An alternate approach could be to delete the author's message and send a new message filtered attachments.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I converted the message to the delete command. It can only be solved like this.